# How should I display notifications on the tab?

Tags: usability, layout

I'm developing a user-script for StackExchange sites, where I display inbox notifications as well as rep change notifications.

Currently, it is displayed in the following way

`[inbox]` if inbox only, `[+rep]` if rep-change only

`[inbox][+rep]` if both.

Now my question is should I display both the notification, or just show the latest notification, may it be inbox or rep, so both won't be displayed together, but only the latest.

What would be more user-friendly? More data or latest data?

Note: I've used square brackets to avoid ambiguity with SE generated `(number)` notification.

Comment: is the `read`/`unread` status available via SE API? if yes, display all unread messages from both categories... and make sure to mark it read when a user clicks on it

Comment: hmm, do you only change the title of the SE page as displayed on the browser's tab or where you want to display the info?

Comment: @Aprillion I just display the numbers.. Not the text

Answer (score 1):

I would display `[1][+0]` for inbox only and `[0][+20]` for reputation only updates, to keep the title consistent with both-updates situation like `[4][+30]`.

I would probably not include seasonal promos like the current [WINTER BASH](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/), but if you want to include it, something like `[1][+0][1]` should be sufficient..

Answer (score 0):

To display the latest information would be more user friednly, since the user would be accessing his own accout.

Users would be more interested what new things have occured since his/her last visit, than looking at the complete old data.(As per human nature this looks more suitable)